# Disabling Custom Keyboard Settings in Android Settings

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am installing a custom keyboard to android. So, when we go to Launcher->Settings and choose "Language and Keyboard", there are 2 keyboards displayed. I can choose between the two keyboards. However, I want to disable this setting and make sure user cannot choose this. How do I do this?